# Performing filter and replace operations against XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

For all tags that have the attribute `TranslateMe`, I need to translate them to some known values.

The flow is:

1. Read file
2. Translate values
3. Reconstruct file

An example of the input file would be:

```
<PatientLastName>Smith</PatientLastName>
<PatientDOB>1956-07-18</PatientDOB>
<PatientSSN>999999999</PatientSSN>
<Facility TranslateMe="Facility">
    <Facility>TheMemorialHospital</Facility>
</Facility>
<FacilityPatientID>AAA</FacilityPatientID>
<FacilityEncounterID>BBB</FacilityEncounterID>
<Interface>
    <Patient>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>Ray</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <DOB>1956-07-18</DOB>
        <Gender TranslateMe="Gender">
            <Gender>F</Gender>
        </Gender>
    </Patient>
</Interface>
```

As you can see above, there are two nodes that will need to be translated: `Facility` and `Gender`.

The desired output would be:

```
<PatientLastName>Smith</PatientLastName>
<PatientDOB>1956-07-18</PatientDOB>
<PatientSSN>999999999</PatientSSN>
<Facility>TheMemorialHospitalTRANSLATEDVALUE</Facility>
<FacilityPatientID>AAA</FacilityPatientID>
<FacilityEncounterID>BBB</FacilityEncounterID>
<Interface>
    <Patient>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>Ray</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <DOB>1956-07-18</DOB>
        <Gender>FTRANSLATEDVALUE</Gender>
    </Patient>
</Interface>
```

**How would I perform these operations on the XML, keeping in mind that I will need to reconstruct the XML message as shown above?**

So far I'm filtering like so:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//element[@name='TranslateMe']");
```

Comment: Iterate over `nodes`, change the values, save the document. There's a good Q&A site on how to do those things, can't remember the name offhand.

Comment: i dont know that mutating the existing message would be the right approach, safest way i believe would be to create a new message with intended updates.

Comment: Just curious...why do you believe it's safer to create a new message? Seems like extra overhead of instantiating another `XmlDocument` and performing a clone or similar mechanism.

Comment: generally we strive towards immutability, especially when the overhead is basically negligeable. check out functional programming in c# or f#

Comment: In general I completely agree. It may be fine in your case. My experience with XML documents is that they are fairly large and a clone operation would immediately double your memory overhead. It all depends.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it. This code

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<root>
    <PatientLastName>Smith</PatientLastName>
    <PatientDOB>1956-07-18</PatientDOB>
    <PatientSSN>999999999</PatientSSN>
    <Facility TranslateMe=""Facility"">
        <Facility>TheMemorialHospital</Facility>
    </Facility>
    <FacilityPatientID>AAA</FacilityPatientID>
    <FacilityEncounterID>BBB</FacilityEncounterID>
    <Interface>
        <Patient>
            <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
            <MiddleInitial>Ray</MiddleInitial>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <DOB>1956-07-18</DOB>
            <Gender TranslateMe=""Gender"">
                <Gender>F</Gender>
            </Gender>
        </Patient>
    </Interface>
    </root>";

    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@TranslateMe]");
    foreach(var node in nodes){
        node.Attribute("TranslateMe").Remove();
        node.Value = Translate(node.Value);
    }
    //xdoc.Dump();
}

public static string Translate(string input){
    // TODO: translate input
    return "TRANSLATED_VALUE";
}
```

produces the following output:

```
<root>
  <PatientLastName>Smith</PatientLastName>
  <PatientDOB>1956-07-18</PatientDOB>
  <PatientSSN>999999999</PatientSSN>
  <Facility>TRANSLATED_VALUE</Facility>
  <FacilityPatientID>AAA</FacilityPatientID>
  <FacilityEncounterID>BBB</FacilityEncounterID>
  <Interface>
    <Patient>
      <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
      <MiddleInitial>Ray</MiddleInitial>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <DOB>1956-07-18</DOB>
      <Gender>TRANSLATED_VALUE</Gender>
    </Patient>
  </Interface>
</root>
```

Comment: makes sense, thanks so much. just wondering how we can perform this without having to change the original message. it would probably involve this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview